# ubuntu クライアントからWindowsファイルサーバーにつなぎたい

Tags: linux, network, ubuntu

ネットワーク初学者です。よろしくお願いします。
ubuntu 15.04 をデスクトップOSとして使用しています。
これをクライアントとし、Windowsファイルサーバー
(Windows server2003)にアクセスして、共有フォルダを
参照できるようにするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 要約すると「Ubuntu DesktopからWIndowsの共有フォルダに接続したいがやり方がわからない」ということでいいでしょうか。

Comment: 多分そうだと思うのですが、何が分からないのか分からないため、下手に先入観を書かずに、自分の理解をそのまま書かせてもらいました。

Comment: ご指摘を受けまして、質問のタイトルと内容を変更しました。

Comment: ファイルサーバーのOSが確認できたので、質問内容とタイトルを再度変更しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ファイルマネージャ(という名称で正しいのかよくわかりませんが)を起動するとウィンドウ左側のメニューの一番下に「Connect to Server」という項目があります。これを選び、入力欄に

```
smb://198.51.100.1
```

などと入力すれば共有フォルダに接続できます。

Answer (score 1):

cifs-utils を利用します。

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

マウントポイントを作成します。

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/server-share
```

マウントします。

```
sudo mount -t cifs //[Windows Server Ip Addr]/[共有名] /mnt/server-share -o username=[Windows Serverのユーザー名],password=[Windows Serverのパスワード],uid=[ubuntuユーザーのuid],gid=[ubuntuユーザーのgid]
```

アクセスします。

```
ls -al /mnt/server-share
```

マウント解除します。

```
sudo umount /mnt/server-share
```

google等で「ubuntu windows ファイル共有 cifs-util」あたりで検索するといろいろヒットするので参照ください。